# How to get img and p tag inside div using vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to get image src and text of `<p>` when I click on `<div>` element.

```
<div class="image-holder" @click="showImage($event)" >
  img class="img-fluid"  src="images/models-detail-small.png" alt="" />
  <p>elevation {{elevationA}}- {{elevationASqt}} sq. ft</p>
</div>


var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    methods: {
        showImage: function (event) {
            element = event.currentTarget;
            console.log(element);

            // href = element.getAttribute('src');
            // this.imgSrc=href;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: There is < missing to the img tag

Answer (score 0):

You should add extra wrapper for hidden elements to toggle visibility

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  
  data: () => ({
    imageVisible: false,
    imgSrc: '',
    text: ''
  }),
  
  
  methods: {
    setData() {
      this.imageVisible = true
      this.imgSrc = 'https://picsum.photos/200/300'
      this.text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor'
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.image-holder {
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 300px;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="image-holder" @click="setData()">
    <div v-if="imageVisible">
      <img class="img-fluid" :src="imgSrc" alt="" />
      <p>{{ text }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need a `<div>` to do that: `<template v-if="imageVisible">` will do the trick, with the bonus of not injecting an additional node in the DOM tree.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are getting the `div` element by `event.CurrentTarget` You can try something like below.

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    methods: {
        showImage: function (event) {
            element = event.currentTarget;
            console.log(element);
            var img = element.getElementsByTagName('img');
            this.imgSrc = img.length > 0 ? img[0].src : null;
            var pTag = element.getElementsByTagName('p');
            this.text = pTag.length > 0 ? pTag[0].textContent : null;
        }
    }
});
```